# Database Variable Java (Static vs enum)

Tags: java, variables, enums, static

I'm just going through my code and tidying things up, standardising things etc.

Just a quick questionin my Database class I have declared the database variables at the start of the class. see below:

```
    private static final String DATABASE = ".....";
    private static final String DRIVER = "....";
```

Is this the best way to do this or would I be best creating an enum and accessing them through that?

Do it really matter at the end of the day?

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum defines a type.

January and February are of type Month.

Mars and Earth are of type Planet.

Those two things don't have any common type. They're just strings. An enum is not appropriate.